# Creating a bidirectional scrollview in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-widget, flutter-layout

I wanted to create a controller somehow like this in Flutter.
[image]

It starts from 1 to 12, after 12 it starts from the beginning (It scrolls infinitely between 1 to 12). I tried it with Listview, but it doesn't work out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You question is missing a lot of information. Please check and follow the question guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can make your Scroll Controller position set to 0 every time the list reaches to 12...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should plugin Swiper and scroll hours according to vertical
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper